# Can you write a Django ManyToMany Custom Cascade Delete?

Tags: django, django-models

I am using Django 3.1 with PostgreSQL.  Here is an example setup:

```
**Tables:**
Batch (id, name)
Data (id, Batch, Stuff(ManyToMany))
Stuff (id, name)
```

Consider this scenario: If I add one record in Batch with the id of 1 and then I add 10,000 records in Data that is linking to Batch#1 and each item might reference some items in the Stuff table.

**Issue:**
If I delete Batch#1 it ends up creating a query like this for deleting the ManyToMany Relationships:

```
DELETE FROM "data_stuff" WHERE "data_stuff"."data_id" IN (1, 2, 3 ... 9999, 10000)
```

That is a lot of IDs listed out.  I would prefer the query to be something like this:

```
DELETE FROM "data_stuff" WHERE "data_stuff"."data_id" IN (SELECT U0."id" FROM "data" U0 WHERE U0."batch_id" = 1)
```

Any ideas of how I can have it generate the SQL like my second example when deleting a Batch record?